# Can't reset root password on MySql Server Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos, root

I've been struggling with this problem for 2 days and I couldn't understand why I'm having this problem.
I've installed MySql server on my Mac, it's working just fine, but I need to reset root password. I followed this tutorial - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html. And when I put this command

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=/Users/user/Documents/mysql-init &
```

I've got this output

```
[1] 2551
bash-3.2# 151127 16:06:07 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro-Mojo.local.err'.
151127 16:06:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
151127 16:06:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro-Mojo.local.pid ended
```

Of course, my password wasn't changed at all. Could you explain me how can I make it work?

Comment: Off topic. Vote to close. Re-ask on Serverfault and supply contents of `/usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro-Mojo.local.err`

Comment: I'll just leave this comment here for two reasons. One being that it might save you time going through possible solutions and two because I'm struggling with a very similar issue and hope you get a working answer soon. ( for a little over two days I'm afraid)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497340/mysql-connect-to-server-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/33709128?noredirect=1#comment55366567_33709128

Answer (score 0):

run this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-N.N
```

where N.N is the MySQL Server version. Mine was 5.5